# Не сохраняется логин в сессии Django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, sqlite

У меня есть три страницы, login, login_cont, login_reg. При неизвестном логине должно быть перенаправление на страницу login_reg. Но при вводе логина в консоль выводится None (print(user_login)). И не перенаправляется, остается на странице login.

```py
#views.py

def login_page(request: WSGIRequest):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            entered_login = form.cleaned_data['login']
            if User.objects.filter(username=entered_login).exists():
                request.session['login'] = entered_login
                return redirect('login_cont')
            else:
                return redirect('login_reg')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'pages/login.html', {'form': form})

def login_cont_page(request: WSGIRequest):
    user_login = request.session.get('login')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(request, username=user_login, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('index')
            else:
                return render(request, 'pages/login_cont.html', {'form': form, 'error_message': 'Invalid password'})
    else:
        form = PasswordForm()

    return render(request, 'pages/login_cont.html', {'form': form, 'user_login': user_login})



def login_reg_page(request: WSGIRequest):
    user_login = request.session.get('login')
    print(user_login)
    if user_login and User.objects.filter(username=user_login).exists():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = RegForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                password = form.cleaned_data['psw']
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=user_login, password=password)
                return redirect('index')
        else:
            form = RegForm()

        return render(request, 'pages/login_reg.html', {'form': form, 'user_login': user_login})
    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где в показанном коде сохранение логина в сессию при неизвестном логине?